# Use "the" before a scientific method name?

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns

I'm writing a paper about an algorithm that I have developed. Just for illustration, I will say that the method name is "quicksort". My question is about the usage of *the* in the following context:

> This paper proposes quicksort, a novel and fast algorithm. The advantage of
>   quicksort is that...

My question is whether I should use "The advantage of *the* quicksort..." or "The advantage of quicksort".

I am also looking for resources explaining the usage of *the* in this context.

---

[Meta]
Usually, to check if a certain sentence is correct, I search Google using wildcards. However, in this case, the correct answer is depends on the context. I have also tried to find a answer in the following book but without success: Science Research Writing: A Guide for Non-Native Speakers of English.

Comment: The advantage of this particular algorithm is...

Comment: If it's your algorithm & it's new, why not capitalize it to make it a proper name? Then you can write "The advantage of **Quicksort** is..." or "The advantage of **the Quicksort algorithm** is...".

Comment: Please put in some background effort, after which if you are still not sure, you may ask on ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is no different from asking where and whether one uses a definite article before any proper noun.  It has nothing to do with science *per se*.

Comment: @Kris I can provide more background information. However, since I'm new here, I'm not sure what kind of information I should provide for this question.

Comment: I was referring to 'background effort' not 'background information' -- you are expected to first do some homework of your own and show it here, like if you referred to your grammar books and if so, what they say; if you searched online, what did you find; and so on.

Comment: @Kris Usually, to check if a certain sentence is correct, I search Google using wildcards. However, in this case, the correct answer is depends on the context. I have also tried to find a answer in the following book but without success: Science Research Writing: A Guide for Non-Native Speakers of English.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a method and you are mentioning a specific example of when you used it, you should use *the* to refer to that specific instance.

If you are referring to the method in general, usually you wouldn't want to use any article in front of it.

If you are referring to a nonspecific instance of using it and just instances of using it in general, you likely want to use *a* or *an* before its name.